# How to map yaml keys to structs in golang?

Tags: go, yaml

I'm looking to write a go script that can parse through a yaml file.  I created a test yaml file with the following:

```
    Dog:
      - name: "Dog"
      - secrets:
          username: "Shiba"
          password: "inu"
          color: "yellow"
    Cat:
      - name: "Cat"
      - secrets:
          words: "meow"
          color: "black"
```

What would the mapping to a struct look like in go?

I've tried along the lines of:

```
            package main

            import (
                "fmt"
                "log"

                "github.com/spf13/viper"
            )

            type Animal struct {
                Animal  []string
                Name    string
                Secrets []map[string]string
            }

            func main() {
                viper.SetConfigName("demo")
                viper.AddConfigPath(".")
                viper.SetConfigType("yaml")

                err := viper.ReadInConfig()

                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                var animal Animal
                err = viper.Unmarshal(&animal)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }

                fmt.Println(animal.Name)
            }
```

But nothing is returned

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: For Viper I thought you called `viper.ReadInConfig()`, not unmarshal - but I could be wrong

Comment: Check out [go-yaml](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)

Comment: I don't think you mean "keys to structs" -- Keys are usually concrete types, like a string or integer.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over your uppermost yml keys ["Dog", "Cat"] and then put it into the struct. If you put this in your config it outputs the name of the animal:

```
name: "Dog"
```